# Defining security groups in Bicep - best practice?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, network-security-groups

To create a VNET and subnets in Azure, we use:

```
resource symbolicname 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-05-01'
```

We can also defined subnets at the same time as we creating VNETs using the parameters in the above resource group.

There is another way to define subnets in Azure, using

```
 Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets
```

However Azure advises us that it is not a best practice to use this method, as they should be defined using the first method.

[“Avoid defining subnets as child resources. This approach can result in downtime for your resources during subsequent deployments, or failed deployments.”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/scenarios-virtual-networks)

When creating security groups, similar to the above, we can create rules at the same time we are creating the security group as per:

```
Microsoft.Network networkSecurityGroups
```

However, we can also create them separately using

```
networkSecurityGroups/securityRules
```

Similar to the VNET Scenario above, is it a best practice to create a SG + rules at the same time, or create them independently?

If this question doesn't make sense apologies - new to this.

Answer (score 0):

> Similar to the VNET Scenario above, is it a best practice to create a
> SG + rules at the same time, or create them independently

AFAIK, Network Security Groups should be deployed in the same way that VMs and other services are. It has to be happening at the same moment. Keeping everything in order.

To do that you can refer [`Microsoft.Network networkSecurityGroups/securityRules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/networksecuritygroups/securityrules?tabs=bicep) & this [*`blog`*](https://dev.to/omiossec/arm-templates-using-nsg-and-application-security-groups-in-your-azure-deployments-1one)